# Android Broadcast not execute when clear from ram

Tags: android, broadcast

Hi i created broadcast receiver which receive Battery level on Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED event. It works good but when i remove this app from ram using swipe from holding home button then it doesnt receive event.
My code of Broadcast is

```
private BroadcastReceiver BatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Toast.makeText(BatteryIndicatorService.this,""+level, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done when your broadcast run in background for that you need to create service.In this service you have to define your Broadcast.

> BatteryIndicatorService.java

```
public class BatteryIndicatorService extends Service {
private BroadcastReceiver BatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Toast.makeText(BatteryIndicatorService.this,""+level, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    // Register Receiver.
    registerReceiver(BatteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onDestroy();
   }
}
```

And Start it from MainActivity like

> MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Start service in Background
    startService(new Intent(this, BatteryIndicatorService.class));
 }
```

Define Service in Manifest.xml in application tag

> manifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name="com.ittl.batteryindicator.BatteryIndicatorService"
        android:enabled="true" >
</service>
```